# Possible to have a row of Divs each with different left starting positions and widths that fill to adjacent sibling?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angular2-template

I'm trying to find a way to insert divs into a container and being able to define the left starting position in pixels of each one while each div automatically has a width that fills to the neighbor sibling's left. I will have an array of the start positions for each div and could therefore calculate the width for each div in the js. But I was hoping for a more elegant solution.

I've searched far and wide for a solution but so far the best I can find is the flex solution relying on calculating the widths:

```css
.s-container {
  height: 20px;
  background-color: red;
  min-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.s-child {
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="s-container">
  <div style="flex-basis:50px;" class="s-child">left: 0</div>
  <div style="flex-basis:100px;" class="s-child">left: 50px</div>
  <div style="flex-grow:1;" class="s-child">left: 150px</div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to give the left position on each div and have each one fill its own width to the neighbor on the right?

Comment: No. this is not possible. The only way to "position" each element is with *actual* `position:absolute` in a relative container. If you do that then the elements are taken out of the flow and you are back where you started.  I'm not quite clear on what effect you looking for but CSS-Grid and `auto-fit/fill` *might* be an option for you.

Comment: @Paulie_D, thanks for the input. From what I have found I think you're right. I guess it was a shot in the dark anyways. I was just hoping to find a solution where I could easily insert a div into a row of other divs, specify the left position on that div, and have the widths adjust automagically. For example, if I have a row of two divs both 200 pixels each and later I insert an additional div at position 100px - my first div should become 100px in width, the second div would be 100px in width, and the third would still be 200 px in width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is a few days late but I wrote a solution that basically looks to the next sibling's start position in order to calculate the current sibling's width while looping through them. I was hoping to avoid doing it this way but it actually turned out pretty nice.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

export class Slide  {
  px: number;    
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
  <div class="s-container">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let s of slides; let i = index; let last = last">
      <div *ngIf="!last" [ngStyle]="{'flex-basis': getSlidePx(i + 1) - s.px + 'px'}" class="s-child">{{s.px}}</div>
      <div *ngIf="last" style="flex-grow:1;" class="s-child">{{s.px}}</div>
    </ng-container>
  </div>

  <form [formGroup]="newSlideForm" (ngSubmit)="onInsert()">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Pixels</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" required formControlName="Pixels" (change)="newSlide.px = $event.target.value" name="pixels">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Insert" [disabled]="!newSlideForm.valid" />
  </form>
  `,
  styles: [`
    .s-container {
      height: 20px;
      background-color: red;
      min-width: 100%;
      display: flex;
    }

    .s-child {
      border-left: 1px solid black;
      background-color: yellow;
      height: 100%;
    }
  `]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  newSlide: Slide;
  newSlideForm: FormGroup;
  slides: Array<Slide>;

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder){
    this.newSlide = new Slide();
    this.newSlideForm = this._fb.group({
      Pixels: [0, Validators.required]
    });
  }

  getSlidePx(n: number){
    if(n < this.slides.length)
      return this.slides[n].px;
  }

  onInsert(){
    this.slides.push(this.newSlide);
    this.slides.sort((a, b) => a.px - b.px);
    this.newSlide = new Slide();
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    let temp = [];

    let s1 = new Slide();
    s1.px = 0;
    temp.push(s1);

    let s2 = new Slide();
    s2.px = 100;
    temp.push(s2);

    let s3 = new Slide();
    s3.px = 210;
    temp.push(s3);

    let s4 = new Slide();
    s4.px = 300;
    temp.push(s4);

    let s5 = new Slide();
    s5.px = 499;
    temp.push(s5);

    let s6 = new Slide();
    s6.px = 650;
    temp.push(s6);

    this.slides = temp;
  }
}
```